# Mechanics problem, car movement with delay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The problem in question is as follows : 
An (infinite) queue of cars stops at a red light, every car has the length $l$ and the distance between two cars is $d$, with the first car $0m$ away from the traffic light. When the light changes from red to green the first car starts immediately with an acceleration $a=1\frac{m}{s}$ and every other car starts $1s$ after the car in front of it.

- Determine expressions for the distance of the $i$'th car from the traffic light at a time $t$
- Suppose $l=2m, d=1m, T = 15s$, with $T$ being the time the green light is turned on. How many cars drive past the traffic light while it is green?

So my take on this is :

- The distance the $i$'th car has to drive to fully cross the traffic light : $s_i = il + (i-1)d$
- The function for time for the $i$'th car :
  $\begin{align*}
  t_i &= 0, \quad t < i-1\\
  t_i &= t - (i-1), \quad t \geq i-1
  \end{align*}$
- The location of the $i$'th car after time $t$ : $x_i = -s_i + a\frac{t_i^2}{2}$ (the traffic light being at $x=0$)

So to solve the second point i used $x_i>0$ as an equation that must be satisfied, meaning that the $i$'th car has fully passed the traffic light i.e. that the it's location is not behind the traffic light. After putting in the equations from above into this condition i get a quadratic function of $i$. Solving it i get $i_1=26.124 \approx 26$ and $i_2=9.876 \approx 9$ (because i want the ones that passed completely). Meaning that $9$ cars have passed the light in time $T=15s$.

My questions are :

- Is the way i am setting up the problem ok and if not why and how can i do it right? (my assumption is that i am not treating the time delay the way i am supposed to)
- How can the two solutions for $i$ be interpreted if my solution is alright?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: Question, Each car has the acceleration a?

Comment: I am sorry for asking it and just the second question would be sufficient, as i understand it is not against the guidelines.

Comment: The acceleration is the same for all cars @Eli

Comment: I use this two equations:

$L_n=n\,L+(n-1)\,d$

and

$t_n=\sqrt{\frac{2\,L_n}{a}}+(n-1)$

if you put $t_n=T$ you can get $n=n(T)=...\,\,$

with your data I got the same result as you got.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your equations seems all right to me.

Note that for 26th car has negative acceleration time ti=15-(26-1)=-10 and therefore you should use the first equation $t_i=0$. But if you don't, this means you assume car was accelerating with the same acceleration for the infinite amount of time both to the past and to the future.

In reality the 26th car was stationary until t=25, but if you assume constant acceleration both to the future and to the past, then the car was decelerating (from infinity) from the direction of the traffic light until it stopped at its distance $s_{26}$ and started moving back toward the traffic lights (to infinity). Therefore, somewhere in the past the car passed the traffic light (x=0), and that would be at the time t=25-10=15, because this is exactly the extreme time the last car was able to pass on green light you were looking for.